# How to reformat output in C using a multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

The problem is that the output must be from a 3x5 table to a 5x3 as shown below

From this:

```
A 90 50 100 10
B 60 100 20 50
C 80 70 100 75
```

To this:

```
A    B    C
90   60   80
50   100  70
100  20   100
10   50   75
```

And it gives me some confusion on how to get to that output.

This is the code that I have made so far:

```
 char n[3]={'A','B','C'};
 int x, y, s[3][4]={90,50,100,10,60,100,20,50,80,70,100,75};

 for(x=0;x<3;x++)
 {
      printf("%c\t",n[x]);
      for(y=0;y<4;y++)
      { 
            printf("%d\t",s[x][y]);
      }
      printf("\n");
 }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Show what you have tried. Hint: it _is_ really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to print the character array first, and then swap the y and x just flip it output that way. Try this:

```
for(x=0; x<3; x++) printf("%c\t", n[x]); //print the char array first
printf("\n");

 for(y=0;y<4;y++)
 {
      for(x=0;x<3;x++)printf("%d\t",s[x][y]);
      printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ForeverStudent. And also thanks for editing my question. My english is bad though

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following like it is shown in the demonstrative program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Rows    3
#define Cols    4

int main( void )
{
    char n[Rows] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
    int s[Rows][Cols] = 
    {
        { 90, 50, 100, 10 }, { 60, 100, 20, 50 }, { 80, 70, 100, 75 }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ ) printf( "%3c ", n[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    for ( int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ ) printf( "%3d ", s[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

The program output

```
  A   B   C 
 90  60  80 
 50 100  70 
100  20 100 
 10  50  75
```